# Weird empty space at the right side of the website (Wordpress twentythirteen)

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I'm currently trying to help out a friend of mine who's just out of college and wants a personal site in the hopes it will help her find a job.

I used wordpress twentythirteen as a base and changed a few things. After a while I noticed that I could scroll the site to the right. the last thing I've added is the sticky footer but I can't find anything in there that might've caused this weird empty space.

I've tried to use the firefox inspector tool too but i can't find what is causing it.

Comment: I can't duplicate your issue. Is there not supposed to be green on the sides?

Comment: Remove padding for body in you css

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce **it in the question itself**.  Please take a tour of the help centre to see how to ask a question

Comment: Thank you all for the quick reply, there was supposed to be some padding on the left and right. The problem was that the site could be scrolled to the right. @ether's answer fixed this for me.

Thanks again for the quick replies

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add `overflow-x:hidden` to your `body` and `html`.

```
html, body, #wrap {
    height: 100%;
    overflow-x: hidden;
}
```

Comment: Just on the HTML and body would do it... Remove the #wrap and the 100% height.

Comment: That is a such a dirty hack, if you don't treat the cause of the problem, this will lead to maintainability issues further down the road

Comment: @Aaron, the `#wrap` and `height:100%` was previously there.

@Pete, if you're building responsive, you will hardly have to worry about it down the road seeing as you never want your content stretching past the window anyways.